# C# .net Member is missing after sending the response

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax

Back-end is C# .Net client is JavaScript.
I'm doing an ajax call to the BE and I return an object contains members.
When I debug on the BE I see the required member when sending the response.
The problem is that on the ajax callback this member is missing!

What can be the problem?

Survey class:

```
    [Serializable]
    public abstract partial class Survey : BaseClass, IInterface1, IInterface1
    {

        [JsonIgnore]
        public List<Rule> Rules
        {
            get { return m_rules; }
            set
            {
                m_rules = value;
                if (m_rules != null)
                {
                    foreach (SurveyRule rule in m_rules)
                    {
                        rule.EnclosingEntity = this;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

BE code - when debugging I see member "Rules" on the survey

```
return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, survey);
```

Client code:

```
_api.myAjaxCall(par1, par2, function (survey) {
    if (callBack) // No Rules member on survey! everything else is there!
        callBack(data);
});
```

Comment: Include your `Survey` class please

Comment: Added survey class

Comment: you have [JsonIgnore] attribute on the property which is ignoring it during serialization

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`[JsonIgnore]` attribute is causing serialization to exclude this property. Remove this attribute and your property will be serialized.